# Best way to navigate parent router from nested Tab Navigator (Nested Navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am using react navigation 5.x, I have navigation stack like this.

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Messages" component={Messages} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
         <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
         <Stack.Navigator>
         <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="OtherScreen1" component={OtherScreen1} />
          <Stack.Screen name="OtherScreen2" component={OtherScreen2} />
         <Stack.Navigator>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Now i need to navigate Feed screen to OtherScreen1. I hope i may have best solution. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I drop 2 options. First your answer your question. The long show how you should use react navigation for good practice.

Short answer

```
navigation.navigate('OtherScreens', { screen: 'OtherScreen1' });
```

Long answer https://snack.expo.io/@anthowm/navigators

```
function Feed() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Feed!</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('OtherScreens', { screen: 'OtherScreen1' });}} title='press'></Button>
    </View>
  );
}

function Messages() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Messages!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function Profile() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Profile!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function Settings() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function OtherScreen1() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>OtherScreen1!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function OtherScreen2() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>OtherScreen2!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function Home() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Messages" component={Messages} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function MainStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStack} />
      <Stack.Screen name="OtherScreens" component={OtherScreensStack} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function ProfileStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function OtherScreensStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="OtherScreen1" component={OtherScreen1} />
      <Stack.Screen name="OtherScreen2" component={OtherScreen2} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}



export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MainStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```